# Show that there isn't any continouos bijection from $(0,1)$ to $S^1$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I couldn't find an answer... Could you give me a hint? I don't want a solution. $S^1$ is a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f\colon(0,1)\longrightarrow S^1$ be such a continuous bijection. Let $x_0\in(0,1)$ be such that $f(x_0)=(-1,0)$. Then the restriction of $f$ to $(0,x_0)\cup(x_0,1)$ is a continuous bijection from $(0,x_0)\cup(x_0,1)$ into $S^1\setminus\{(-1,0)\}$, which is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$. So, there would be a continuous bijection $F$ from $(0,x_0)\cup(x_0,1)$ onto $(0,1)$. A standard Real Analysis theorem says that the inverse of such a function must be continuous. In other words, $(0,x_0)\cup(x_0,1)$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic. This is impossible, since $(0,x_0)\cup(x_0,1)$ isn't connected, whereas $(0,1)$ is.

Comment: OP needs to know about direct sum (disjoint union) topological spaces to follow your argument.

Comment: @MikeMathMan Why? I sure did not think in those terms.

Comment: I thought the standard Real Analysis theorem is about interval mappings $I$ to the real numbers.

Comment: @MikeMathMan What I had in mind is the statement that if $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ and $f\colon A\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is injective and continuous, then $f^{-1}\colon f(A)\longrightarrow A$ is also continuous.

Comment: I guess some work is needed, so you've provided a good hint.

Comment: yes - I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider any continuous injective function $f$ mapping from $(0, 1)$ to $S^1$.

Look at the image under $f$ of the open intervals

$(2^{-n},\; 1-2^{-n})$ for $n \gt 1$.

The sequence $f(2^{-n})$ has a limit $z_0$ on the circle. Show that $f$ can never take on that value.